# How to bulide a Angular Project without Angular CLI?

Tags: angular

I have a code challenge.
He ask me to design a web with Angular and Bootstrap, and I cannot use Angular 2 and Angular CLI.
How can I run a Angular project without Angular CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use the CLI then you'll have to manually install all the necessary Angular packages and configure it yourself.

Here's a link that might be able to help you out with that: https://blog.angularindepth.com/setting-up-angular-from-scratch-1f518c65d8ab.